# Is there a way to let the bot check message content?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Is it possible to check any message in a channel for its content?
I want a discord bot to react only to messages containing a link, or some media (music, video, image...). It should ignore normal text messages.

How do I check message content with discord.py ? Does it have a function to do so?
I could not find anything in the docs but may have overlooked something. I also don't know which information is passed with `on_message(message)`. Characters, content ?

Thanks for all pointers in the right direction.

Comment: Have you tried accessing `message.content`? Here's a [basic example](https://github.com/GreatTaku/Discord-Bot-Examples/blob/master/rewrite/on_message.py) of receiving a messages and displaying the content.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Thanks that helps me in a way, but it doesn't provide me with attachments of a message, which is my main concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`on_message()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#message) event. With this event, you get every message's information(content, author, creation date etc.) including the [`attachments`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.attachments). With this, you can get all the attachments from a message. Here is a basic usage:

```
link_list = ['.com', '.net']
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    if message.attachments:
        [print attachment for attachment in message.attachments]
    [print(message.content) for link in link_list if link in message.content]
```

So this will print out all the attachments from a message and if message has link, it will print the message content too. You can expand the `link_list`. This is basicly what you need.

Comment: Thanks for this, I think its what I was searching for. 
What does "if message.attachments:" do exactly? Does this simply check whether a message has any attachments and then returns, or does it get attachments.

Comment: It checks if there is a attachment(video, media) in message. If there is, it returns a list with the attachments id-attachments name-attachments link.